# Piping to Secondary Output File

Tags: redirect, pipe

Trying to pipe commands and redirect to a second output file.

Individually, I can operate the following command lines and I get the correct sorted file.

`cut -c 63-69 Data.txt >T_DAILY_AVG.txt`
`sort <T_DAILY_AVG.txt >T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt`

However, when I attempt to pipe the commands together, I get the correct T_DAILY_AVG.txt file but the T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt returns empty. This is the command line I am attempting to use.

`cut -c 63-69 Data.txt >T_DAILY_AVG.txt | sort <T_DAILY_AVG.txt >T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) which is the Linux program that writes the input to a file AND prints it back out to `stdout`.

`cut -c 63-69 Data.txt | tee T_DAILY_AVG.txt | sort > T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt`

I tested it with some dummy data to show that it works:

```sh
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | tee T_DAILY_AVG.txt | sort > T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt
$ cat T_DAILY_AVG.txt 
one
two
three
$ cat T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt 
one
three
two
```

Alternately, you could just run it as two separate commands.  The first command writes to a file.  The second command reads that file and writes to a different file.  I would use `&&` in between them so that the second command runs only if the first command succeeds.

```sh
$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' > T_DAILY_AVG.txt && sort T_DAILY_AVG.txt > T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt
$ cat T_DAILY_AVG.txt 
one
two
three
$ cat T_DAILY_AVG_sorted.txt 
one
three
two
```